# How to delete carriage return from Pandas Headers when reading an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to read excel function in pandas and remove carriage returns found in the headers.

I have found multiple answers pointing out how to remove them in the data but not specifically in the headers.

I have tried a few things, see below, but not working. Any advice appreciated thanks.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('S:/DataToClean.xlsm',skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Which headers?  Show us an example.  In most Excel spreadsheets, the headers are just another row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df1 = (pd.read_excel('S:/DataToClean.xlsm',skiprows=1)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip()))

# Or simply:
df1.colums = df1.columns.str.strip()
```